# Is there a way to hide Java methods in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, extension-methods

I'm learning Kotlin and I'm reading this days *Kotlin in Action*.
Reading the chapter about extension functions and standard library improvement, I read about different behaviour exposed by `String.split` overloads between Java and Kotlin: I think it's a very good idea to move toward an explicit and more type-guided separation between delimiters-based and regex-based overloads.

About this, the book I've mentioned above says that *Kotlin hides the confusing method and provides as replacements several overloaded extensions named `split` that have different arguments*.

Extension functions respond to the questione "How can I add method to an existing class"; on the other hand, **I can't figure out how it's possibile to *hide* methods provided by the Java Standard Library**.

I did some attempts writing simple code, and I noticed that

1. `val ks = "Pietro Martinelli"` has `ks::class.qualifiedName == "kotlin.String"`
2. `val ks = "Pietro Martinelli"` has `ks::javaClass.name == "java.lang.String"`
3. passing the above value `ks` to a Java method, the received parameter `x` has `x.getClass().getName() == "java.lang.String"` (as expected)
4. `String js = "Pietro Martinelli"` (in Java code) has `js.getClass().getName() == "java.lang.String"`, as expected
5. passing the above `js` value to a Kotlin method, the received parameter `y` has `y::class.qualifiedName == "kotlin.String"` and `y.getClass().getName() == "java.lang.String"` (as so far expected)

So: it seems that (let me say) *something magic* occurred when I use `String` values in Kotlin and back and forth from Kotlin to Java. If I undestand correctly, `String` literals in Kotlin are instances of `kotlin.String` but they are bounded to a *Java type* that is transparently used for Java method calls. This way Kotlin library can enhance `String` experience without affecting `java.lang.String`: usual Java `[java.lang.]String.split` methods are *hidden* to Kotlin code in the sense that Kotlin developers see `[kotlin.]String` instances and their methods.

So, two (related) question:
 1. is my understanding right? And, more interesting
 2. it's only a kind of magic put in place by the compiler, which *knows* `String`s as instances of a *special* type and wraps them behind instances of a different class, or is there some more general approach/mechanic that permits to someway *hide* some method of a class the same way we can add methods through the extension function mechanic? It can be very dangerous, so **I think it's only a matter of the compiler**, but it can be powerful, too, so I think it's worth the question.

Thank in advance for hints and feedbacks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is compiler magic. These are called [mapped types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types), and the compiler gives them special treatment to make it so that they are visible to Kotlin code as the Kotlin types that have modified interfaces, even though at runtime they are instances of the regular Java types when compiled to the JVM.

Other than `String`, the most notable examples perhaps are the collections, which have two layers of completely new interfaces applied to them, for the read-only and mutable variants.